# Get data from list of object in C#

Tags: c#, list

I want to get id,name and currency form my list products : 1 - TID - 13.2

```
namespace Test
{
    class Product
    {
        private int id;
        private string name;
        private double currency;
        List<Product> products = new List<Product>();
        public Product(int id,string name,double currency)
        {
            this.id = id;
            this.name = name;
            this.currency = currency;
        }
        public void addProduct(Product product)
        {
            products.Add(product);
        }
        public void listOfProducts()
        {
            foreach (object o in products)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(o);
            }
        }
    }
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Product p = new Product(1, "TID", 13.2);
            p.addProduct(p);
            p.listOfProducts();
        }
    }
}
```

but when I execute this code I get Test.product
Can someone told me what should I to get data from my list not the list name

Comment: Change `object` to `Product` and  `Console.WriteLine(o);` to `Console.WriteLine($"{o.id} - {o.name} - {o.currency}");`

Comment: There is a missunderstanding in your code. You declare products in your instance so that all products have their own products property. That should be `static public List<Product> products ` although this is not answer to your question

Comment: @İhsanCemilÇiçek I wish if you answer my question :)

Comment: It makes no sense that each instance of `Product` contains a `List<Product>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You output the object itself, but if you don't override `ToString` it just outputs the type-name. You also cast the `Product` to `Object`, so you won't be able to use `Product` properties. Instead use:

```
foreach (Product p in products)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{p.Id} - {p.Name} - {p.Currency}");
}
```

I have used (public) properties, currently you just have private fields. So edit your class like here:

```
public class Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public double Currency { get; set; }
    List<Product> Products { get; set; }

    public Product(int id, string name, double currency)
    {
        this.Id = id;
        this.Name = name;
        this.Currency = currency;
        this.Products = new List<Product>();
    }
    // ...
}
```

Comment: I receive this error "object doesn't contain a definition for id "

Comment: @Saad: yes, as mentioned in my last sentence you have to provide the (public) properties, you currently just have private fields which can't be accessed from outside. You could simply make them `public`, but public fields are rarely a good idea. Encapsulate them as property.

Comment: Sorry but still dont understand can you tell me what I should add to my code

Comment: I wish this answer would show how to override `ToString()` and what effect it has on `Writeline(item)`

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to show you some code with best practices with `C#` programming. Some of the features included are:

- Immutable object `Product` with properties of `Quantity`, `Name` and `Currency`. Currency needs to be of `decimal` type if it is to store currency type values. Properties have [PascalCase](https://github.com/ktaranov/naming-convention/blob/master/C%23%20Coding%20Standards%20and%20Naming%20Conventions.md) naming convention.
- Define equality comparing values via `.Equals(Product other)` and use this method within the .NET Framework by implementing `IEquatable<Product>` interface.
- Convert any `Product` into a `string` via the `.ToString()` method, and implement a reverse parsing of text into a `Product` via the `.Parse(text)` static method
- Removed the `List<Product>` from inside *every single instance* of a product as it is recommended to be defined locally of where it is going to be used.
- Implement `GetHashCode()` per best practices for when `Product` is used in a `Dictionary` collection.
- I have some test code in the end that tests all this code

### Class definition

```
public class Product : IEquatable<Product>
{
    public int ID { get; }
    public string Name { get; }
    public decimal Currency { get; }

    public Product(int id, string name, decimal currency)
    {
        this.ID= id;
        this.Name=name;
        this.Currency=currency;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Converts a Product into a string description of itself.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>
    /// A <see cref="string"/> of the form <![CDATA["123 - ABC - 3.21"]]> with quantity, name and currency.
    /// </returns>
    public override string ToString() => $"{ID} - {Name} - {Currency}";

    /// <summary>
    /// Parses text into a Product.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="description">The description of the Product. Expecting the description 
    /// to be of the form <![CDATA["123 - ABC - 3.21"]]> with quantity, name and currency.</param>
    /// <returns>A new Product or null</returns>
    public static Product Parse(string description)
    {
        string[] parts = description.Split('-');
        if(parts.Length==3)
        {
            if(int.TryParse(parts[0].Trim(), out int id))
            {
                string name = parts[1].Trim();
                if(decimal.TryParse(parts[2].Trim(), out decimal currency))
                {
                    return new Product(id, name, currency);
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Determines whether the specified <see cref="System.Object" />, is equal to this instance.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="obj">The <see cref="System.Object" /> to compare with this instance.</param>
    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if(obj is Product product)
        {
            return Equals(product);
        }
        return false;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Indicates whether the current object is equal to another object of the same type.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="other">A Product to compare with this Product.</param>
    public bool Equals(Product other)
    {
        return other!=null
            && ID==other.ID
            && Name==other.Name
            && Currency==other.Currency;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        int hashCode = 1486216620;
        hashCode=hashCode*-1521134295+ID.GetHashCode();
        hashCode=hashCode*-1521134295+EqualityComparer<string>.Default.GetHashCode(Name);
        hashCode=hashCode*-1521134295+Currency.GetHashCode();
        return hashCode;
    }
}
```

### Test Code

```
/// <summary>
/// Code for https://stackoverflow.com/q/53321654/380384
/// </summary>
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var all = new List<Product>();
        all.Add(new Product(1, "TID", 13.2m));
        all.Add(new Product(2, "TJQ", 11.8m));
        all.Add(new Product(3, "UIZ", 15.7m));
        string description = "4 - UYA - 18.4";
        all.Add(Product.Parse(description));

        foreach(Product item in all)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item);
        }
        //1 - TID - 13.2
        //2 - TJQ - 11.8
        //3 - UIZ - 15.7
        //4 - UYA - 18.4

        if(all[3].ToString().Equals(description))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(@"Product -> String is ok.");
        }
        if(Product.Parse(description).Equals(all[3]))
        {
            Console.Write(@"String -> Product is ok.");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You have some programatic problems rather than looping through product list. You need to understand difference between static and non-static types. Static methods are belongs to the class itself. So that when you write static before your declaration to say that this variable or method is for class and not instances.

The other problem with your code was for loop obviously. You should iterate over Product type and not object since object has not have same members as Product.

```
namespace Test
{
    class Product
    {
        static private List<Product> Products;

        private int id;
        private string name;
        private double currency;

        public Product(int id, string name, double currency)
        {
            this.id = id;
            this.name = name;
            this.currency = currency;
        }

        public static void AddProduct(Product product)
        {
            if (Products == null)
            {
                Products = new List<Product>();
            }
            Products.Add(product);
        }

        public static void GetListOfProducts()
        {
            foreach (Product product in Products)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(String.Format("id:{0} name:{1} currency:{2}", product.id, product.name, product.currency));
            }
        }
    }


    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Product p = new Product(1, "TID", 13.2);
            Product.AddProduct(p);
            Product.GetListOfProducts();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Saad what happened. Why did you unaccept my answer and why did you downvote?